# installing isolated gcc on server without sudo

Tags: gcc, installation

I have access to a server (but don't have root permissions on there). To cut a long story short the admin won't upgrade to the newer version of gcc that I need, but has suggested that I can just install it locally.

I'm having some issues doing this, despite trying to follow the guide at http://gcc.gnu.org/install/index.html. I want to use the new versions of GMP, MPFR, and MPC that are installed now on the server.

I first go into my home dir on the server then `mkdir mygcc` which I then `cd` into (this is to be the build dir and is not a sub-dir of src dir), from there I do

```
/home/username/gcc-4.6.3/configure --with-gmp="/software/gmp-5.0.5" --with-  
gmp-include="/software/gmp-5.0.5/include" --with-gmp-lib="/software/gmp-5.0.5/lib" 
--with-mpfr="/software/mpfr-3.1.1" --with-mpfr-include="/software/mpfr-3.1.1/include"
--with-mpfr-lib="/software/mpfr-3.1.1/lib" --with-mpc-include="/home/username/usr/local
/include" --with-mpc-lib="/home/username/usr/local/lib" --prefix="/home/username/mygcc"
 --with-local-prefix="/home/username/usr/local"
```

the src files that I unzipped are at `/home/pmxlh1/gcc-4.6.3`.

I also made the directories `/home/username/usr/include`, `/home/username/usr/local` etc and set the prefix flags to try and install various things there, but it also fails if I just leave those flags out for the same reasons.

When I get to make however it ends with

```
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/home/pmxlh1/mygcc/x86_64-  
unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/pmxlh1/mygcc'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pmxlh1/mygcc'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Not sure if I'm going about this the correct way? But basically I want to install it in my home/dir and so that it uses the correct GMP/MPFR/MPC not the old versions that maybe lurking elsewhere on the server.

thanks for any help

Comment: I've also tried following: http://advogato.org/person/redi/diary/253.html to the letter, but get: checking for MPFR... yes
checking for recent GMP... yes
checking for recent MPFR... no
configure: error: MPFR version >= 2.4.2 required
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-mpc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/pmxlh1/gcc-temp/objdir'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pmxlh1/gcc-temp/objdir'
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: I can't see why as in the sources dir, you can clearly see mpfr-3.1.1 and the sym link mpfr (and similarly for gmp and mpc)